# Use flag in two Activity connect (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm building an android application, with two activities: **MainActivity** and **PlayMovieActivity**. In the **MainActivity** , I have one button to start play movie Activity , like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent setClassName("xxx.xxx","xxx.startmovie");
startActivity(intent);
```

Unfortunately , that connect not always smooth , sometime , it will not connect. 
I try to use a flag to judgment connect or not connect. Is there any way to do it ?

in fact , intent to another Activity is OK , but sometimes it's not ok . I don't
know . if playmovie Activity not working , the button is visible can let you press again, but if it's working , the button is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

> An Intent is an object that provides runtime binding between separate
>   components, such as two activities. The Intent represents an app’s
>   "intent to do something."

Remove `setClassName`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,PlayMovieActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayMovieActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```